# How to pop specific values in 2D array

Tags: python

I am trying to remove number 5 from the 2D array

```
d = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
d[1][2].pop()
#number 5 should be popped
print(d)
```

but I keep getting this error code

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass index of element you want to pop as argument of `list.pop()` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)):

```
d[1].pop(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in removing the item, you can use `del`.

```
In [4]: d = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

In [5]: del(d[1][2])

In [6]: d
Out[6]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```